# Stop a page from scrolling when showing a hidden div

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I have a tab pane that is inside a fixed size div, whenever that tab is switched to one that is larger than the outer div the entire page is scrolling down such that I cannot see my tabs anymore, I've mocked it up in jsfiddle to show the problem.

Note that in order to see the problem the page must be smaller than the containing div.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vVJY4/1/)

Anyone know how I can stop the page from scrolling down when the tabs switch without using javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to to is `evt.preventDefault();`:

http://jsfiddle.net/vVJY4/2/

Comment: This is a stunning answer. For years, I have wondered how to stop this behaviour. The thing is, I understand why it is happening. Because content is being added & removed from the page flow, the scroll position has to change accordingly, but I am at a loss to understand why your solution actually works? Anyway, thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for showing me the evt.preventDefault() It got me to look in the right spot. The link when clicked points to my hidden div which the page then scrolls down to.

To stop the scrolling I can also just remove the id from the href attribute to something else,

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vVJY4/4/)

Comment: For `accessibility` and `graceful degradation` purposes, I'll strongly advise you to keep those named anchors in there.

Comment: Also, to say that this is a solution without using JavaScript is just like saying removing the anchors all together is a solution.  In fact, don't even write a page at all, it's a solution!

Comment: @Adam I originally thought it was a problem with some of my css being screwy and not the href attr. being the cause. I didn't want answers the corrected the scroll rather ones that never had the scroll in the first place if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 0):

*Without* using JavaScript?  Cannot be done.

Using JavaScript it's easy:

```
evt.preventDefault();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vVJY4/3/

Comment: He meant to say that he dosn't want to get out of his comfort zone of using jQuery ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use „pure” JavaScript, use:

```
function stopScroll()
{
    document.getElementById("body_id").style.overflow = "hidden";
}

function startScroll()
{
    document.getElementById("body_id").style.overflow = "auto";
}
```